# How to get share count of an url in Google Plus by passing only url

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I want to get share count for a particular url from Google Plus.I tried by passing activity id in [Activities: get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/get) to get share count. It is working fine but I want the same by passing only url alone.

In Facebook I passed only the Url as input in [query url with input url](http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.maalaimalar.com/News/TopNews/2017/11/21184140/1130215/Watch-film-before-opposing-Union-min-Birender-Singh.vpf) and i got share counts for an url.Is there any ways available in Google Plus to get the share count by passing only url.

**Referred site:**
[jonathanmoore/gist:2640302](https://gist.github.com/jonathanmoore/2640302)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of Google APIs.   The method in question

Activites.get

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/activityId
```

Takes a single parameter

> activityId string  The ID of the activity to get.

This is how this method works you must pass an activityId to it you can not pass a url.  I can suggest running an [Activies.list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list) first in order to find the activity you seek.

Answer (score 0):

You're best option is to use the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/search). Use the URL as the search term and page through all of the results until no more are found. You then have a number for how many times the URL has been shared publicly on Google+.